# Spring map entries versus resources

Tags: spring, resources

Consider a factory bean. It takes a single property of type `Map<String, Object>`. It carefully checks all the Objects for 'instanceof Resource' and does resource processing appropriately.

I configure this bean like:

```
<bean id='fact' class='my.class'>
  <property name='map'>
    <map>
      <entry key="x" value="file:/WEB-INF/foo.txt"/>
    </map>
  </property>
 </bean>
```

In the debugger, I see that the setter for the property is called with a Map, and the value is a java.lang.String with the file: still sitting on it.

Since there is no explicit prefix for servlet context resources, I am now officially puzzled.

In my previous question, the 'solution' turned out to be to correct a really stupid default configuration of the maven-jetty-plugin.

Apologies for the rewrite, but no one answered yet :-)

Comment: Can't you use the solution from your last question for this?(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390872/how-to-set-a-property-in-spring-to-a-pathname-inside-of-web-inf)

Comment: @ska I've been a bad person and replaced the contents of this question after, duh, actually debugging a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More and more googling eventually revealed:

```
<entry key="grammarURL">
            <value type="org.springframework.core.io.Resource">classpath:/com/basistech/ras/rules.jape</value>
</entry>
```